# Is it possible to change the display size for multiple displays?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

So I'm using two monitors. One's my laptop and the other's a normal desktop monitor. The laptop's 15 inches and the other monitor's much bigger (I don't know the exact size but I think 27 inches).

I use both monitors, but the problem is that since the screen sizes are different in real life and it doesn't seem that Windows can detect that, it gets slightly annoying when I move sideways to the other monitor and the cursor doesn't move smoothly across.

Anyway, I'm wondering if there is a way to change the size in the display settings?

More specifically,

Can I manually change the size for display 1?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Screen sizes in this view are based on resolutions adjusted for scaling. Both of your screens use identical resolutions and (I assume) 100% scaling, so Windows aligns corresponding pixels next to each other.

If you want the laptop display to appear smaller, you have to enable scaling - probably 125% or 150% will be appropriate. Click the smaller screen and change scaling on the page below.

Be aware that this will "waste" some pixels - UI elements on the smaller screen will be enlarged by the scaling factor. Dragging windows from one screen to the other will be weird too, they will shrink or enlarge abruptly when crossing the screen border.